# Django - Receiving JSON from Google Maps API

Tags: python, django, json

I am trying to retrieve some data from the Google Maps API from a Django app.

```
req = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Manchester'
data = urllib.urlopen(req).read()
jsondata = simplejson.loads(data)
```

However, the above gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 9: unexpected code byte.
```

Is there an easy way around this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback.

Comment: Ignore my answer, try taking out the %20 from your req

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps returns response in ISO-8859-1 encoding. You need to decode the `data` bytestring before passing it to simplejson:

```
jsondata = simplejson.loads(data.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```